# Center elements in LinearLayout after creating it programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, position, android-linearlayout, center

I'm creating a LinearLayout on Runtime in which I'm adding a two elements: a textview and a spinner.
I would like to center them horizontally in the LinearLayout, but cannot figure out how to do it. Below, the code that I use to create my views:

```
LinearLayout leftSideAttributLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

leftSideAttributLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams attributLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
leftSideAttributLayout.setLayoutParams(attributLayoutParams);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams leftLabelParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
leftLabelParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
leftAttributLabel.setLayoutParams(leftLabelParams);         
TextView leftAttributLabel = new TextView(this);

leftAttributLabel.setText(attribut.getNom());
leftAttributLabel.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Tools.applyFont(getApplicationContext(), leftAttributLabel, "gothic_0.TTF");

LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
spinnerParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
spinnerParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);

Spinner leftAttributValues = new Spinner(this);
leftAttributValues.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);
leftAttributValues.setAdapter(adapter);
leftAttributValues.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lenti_attributspinner);
leftAttributValues.setTag(attribut);
```

Would be great if someone could help me with that ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

because you have to set gravity to linearlayout itself so just put this line after setting your linear layout parameter

```
leftSideAttributLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

here is sample from your code

```
 LinearLayout leftSideAttributLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

            leftSideAttributLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams attributLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            attributLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;


            leftSideAttributLayout.setLayoutParams(attributLayoutParams);
            leftSideAttributLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams leftLabelParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            //leftLabelParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

            TextView leftAttributLabel = new TextView(this);

            leftAttributLabel.setText("sample");
            leftAttributLabel.setTextSize(25);
            leftAttributLabel.setLayoutParams(leftLabelParams);


            LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           // spinnerParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            spinnerParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);

            Spinner leftAttributValues = new Spinner(this);
            leftAttributValues.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);

            leftSideAttributLayout.addView(leftAttributLabel);
            leftSideAttributLayout.addView(leftAttributValues);

            mainview.addView(leftSideAttributLayout);
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Generating layout and positionning is a bit tricky on runtime !

Comment: this is tricky but worked. Why is it needed on the layout itself and setting on the layoutparams doesnt have any effect?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you get the params from the `Layout`, not from the `Spinner`, so your attribute size is fullscreen, which makes gravity modifications without effect.

Use this:

```
Spinner leftAttributValues = new Spinner(this);
leftAttributValues.setAdapter(adapter);
leftAttributValues.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lenti_attributspinner);
leftAttributValues.setTag(attribut);

// get actual spinner params
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) leftAttributValues.getLayoutParams();
// modify desired params 
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
// set modified params to spinner again
leftAttributValues.setLayoutParams(params);
```